# Object as a parameter?

Tags: java, interface-implementation

I had asked a question about implementing a class by subclass in Java previously and I found a different approach used.(different for me!)
URL: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22987613/what-is-class-implementation-in-java/22988086?noredirect=1#22988086)

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
```

this line was confusing for me, for a class was passed as a parameter. Well, I thought of giving a try and understand before I asked here. Here's my code:

```
public class parameterObject{

String name;
int age;

public parameterObject(){}
public parameterObject(String inputName,int inputAge){

    name = inputName;
    age = inputAge;

}
public void testObject(){

System.out.println(name);
System.out.println(age);
}

}
```

and in the next class, I used a method to pass `parameterObject` as a parameter (in bjueJ environment)

```
public void testFunction(parameterObject pO, int a){
 pO.testObject();
}
```

when I called the method, `testFunction(...)`It asked for parameter values and I entered `"arpan",19 and 20`.
error:  expected..
and then I tried using `null` for the objectParameter and then the JVM threw `nullPointException` error.. 
what was supposed to happen and what is lacking in my understanding? please help.

Comment: No class is being passed as a parameter. An instance of Graphics is being passed as a parameter. Your problem is obscure and your question unclear.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand what you did , i think you did like that:

```
X.testFunction("arpan", 19, 20);
```

which is not right, u have to do like this:

```
X.testFunction(new parameterObject("arpan", 19), 20);
```

Comment: if you need more explanation just ask!

Comment: Here is the screenshoot of what happened to the function when I ran it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vnnnfq61m17z5li/Screenshot%20from%202014-04-15%2010%3A43%3A36.png

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly `testFunction` expects two parameters: First `p0` of type `parameterObject` and then `a` of type `int`.

Did you call the method like this: `testFunction("arpan", 19, 20)`?

This call wouldn't "match the method signature". That means the types of the values you passed in don't match with those the method expects.
`"arpan"` is a String and `19, 20` are **two** int.

You could do something like this instead:

```
parameterObject abc = new parameterObject("arpan", 19);
testFunction(abc, 17);  // one parameterObject and one int - just like testFunction expects
```